# Is there a way to update a list item on another list via a field value as a "field value assignment"?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

If I had a **field named "type of fruit"** with a value of "apple" ( to correlate to a **field named of the same name "apple"** on another list named "fruits") is there a way to use the aforementioned value of **"type of fruit**" to dynamically "set the field" in "value assignment" and update the **field of the same name as the value of "type of fruit"**  on another list with a value of let's say "*true*"?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can update a list item on another list based on a field value on the current list as the following.

- Open your workflow via SharePoint Designer.
- In your workflow Stage/Step based on your workflow platform 2010 /2013 > Add an action called `Update List Item` below `list actions`

[image]

- Now click on this list to specify the list that you need to update its field. (In your case it's Fruit).
- In `Update list Item` dialog specify your list (In your case it's Fruit).
- Click add to specify the field that you need to set its value with a value from your current list item.

[image]

- At `Find List Item` section, you should find the relation between your first list to another (fruit). (in your case, you don't have ID relationship, you just has Type of Fruit in the first list and Fruit name in the second list. So you should specify the field that holds the fruit name in the second list (Fruit) with the value of a type of Fruit in the current item.

New Image:

[image]

Comment: specify the field of the same name. Is that possible? Because at the would just be able to select one of the Apple field ( I.e. Apple 2 )  names to update but what if it is not the value from the dropdown select ( i.e. Apple 3 )? Apple 3 would then not match the "Apple2" select to update the list. 
It would be so awesome if there is a way.Thank you again friend.

Comment: Hi @MikeRooker should you please read this line again, At Find List Item section, you should find the relation between your first list to another (fruit). (in your case, you don't have ID relationship, you just has Type of Fruit in the first list and Fruit name in the second list. So you should specify the field that holds the fruit name in the second list (Fruit) with the value of a type of Fruit in the current item.

Comment: Hello M.Qassas, Forgive me if I am missing something. Here is where I am lost. ( Please see diagram ). At the source page a value ("M5") from a dropdown is selected and is to match a field name at the update list  .In this instance ,  M5 is the value I'd like to carry over to the field set with a value of "true". But If I manually select M5 for the set field in update list then what happens when the workflow runs and the value being put through is M4 or M7.

Comment: I understand the "Find the List Item" dialog box needs to be filled but how do I dynamically select the field in "add a "value assignment" automatically from the value brought into the workflow?

Comment: I added a new image to the original post below. Thanks again M.Qassas

Comment: let me check this

Comment: you mean each column field has a type of fruit

Comment: Yes Sir. I know. It doesn't seem doable.